# Panic error when creating Presigned url

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3

I'm trying to create a presigned url using the aws-sdk-go, but it it's failing with the following output:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x18 pc=0x138d40a]

goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3.New(0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /Users/me/go/src/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3/service.go:47 +0x3a
main.main()
    /Users/me/go/src/Test/main.go:22 +0xa0
exit status 2
```

I'm not seeing where I'm making a mistake, perhaps someone more experience in go could point out to me:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "time"

    // "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3"
    "github.com/kelseyhightower/envconfig"
)


func main() {
  var configuration s3.PutObjectInput
  err := envconfig.Process("configuration", &configuration)

  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err.Error())
  }

  svc := s3.New(nil)
  req, _ := svc.PutObjectRequest(&configuration)
  url, err := req.Presign(15 * time.Minute)
  fmt.Println("The url is ", url)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a `nil` session while initialising s3 service `svc := s3.New(nil)`, that why you get the nil pointer error.

You can pass the session using following code,

new `import "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"`

```
awsSession = session.Must(session.NewSessionWithOptions(session.Options{
    SharedConfigState: session.SharedConfigEnable,
}))
// Create S3 service client
serviceS3 = s3.New(awsSession)
```

You might need to change the session configurations based on how you plan to use the credentials. You can read more about credential configurations here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/